# How to wait for a response from a particular app?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm not sure if my question fits really on my problem. So here is the scenario.

I have two apps, "App A" that handles calculations or logical operations(basically the brain) and "App B" just basically do whatever the App A says. App A sends commands to App B (like Make a Call, Talk, Walk etc-) and App B process/performs this tasks. Once it is done performing the command it sends a response back to App A that it is done (I used RabbitMQ in the middle to handle messaging between apps).Messages/Commands from App A is identified by message ID, App B sends back this message ID so that App A knows who's the owner of the message. I need App A to wait for App B to response from a particular command. How do I achieve this?

Best regards,

Comment: [The Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) might be the right tool for the job.

Comment: Which client library for C# are you using? The RabbitMQ client, EasyNetQ, Burrow, etc...? You need to perform old-fashion RPC-style calls if you want to "block" AppA until AppB responds.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I used RabbitMQ client, No no- "block" is not ideal. AppA should be able to send other commands while the first command is processed by AppB and waiting for response.